# Admin account triggering multiple transactions for P2E game

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, web3js, ethers.js, moralis

I just watched [Build a Play2Earn game](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h31YcNgAIUw&ab_channel=MoralisWeb3) tutorial on youtube.

So whenever the game is done and player won, `playerWon()` from smart contract is called by moralis cloud which uses admin private key.

Question here is, what if 1k or 10k people played the game and won simultaneously or between the similar time? I know it'd be hectic for one admin account to process tons of transactions at the same time because of the nonce issue.

What's the production level solution to this?

Comment: You don't need to worry about it. The Moralis Cloud Functions is scalable, it means it will run in parallel all requests posted. Maybe your Moralis plan will not give you a rate limit capable to comport this amount of transactions: https://v1docs.moralis.io/misc/rate-limit

Comment: oh wow that's crazy. wonder how they are doing it in parallel using only one account. what do you think of adding a private key in moralis cloud, i'm also worried about the security side

Comment: @JoVi ok so their rate-limit doc is for limiting the number of api calls. It is not related nor does not scale multiple transactions that requires different nonces

Comment: The nonce is incremental. And the nonce issue is when we have different wallets signing transactions. If you do it using the same wallet/service (in the case Moralis) this problem should not occur, but for best practices in your game, I  would recommend to keep track of failed transactions anyway. About adding a key in any cloud service, I would say that you need to trust in the service (Moralis or not).
https://github.com/ethereumbook/ethereumbook/blob/develop/06transactions.asciidoc#the-transaction-nonce

Comment: ok thanks that link was certainly valuable. But i'm still wondering how moralis can process say 100 transactions at the same time in parallel using only one admin account.

Comment: This is because i’ve already used web3.js to make multiple transactions simultaneously by adding different nonces manually using `web3.eth.getTransactionCount(accountAddress, 'pending')`, but like in this [thread](https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/1741) I’ve also encountered some errors -probably out of sync. Also, for [ethers.js](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/issues/435) having similar problem. So I assume moralis might not be able to run this smoothly as well and using some sort of queuing system would probably make sense to process them in batches. What do you think?

Comment: you are absolutelly right. I re-read the docs, and they will NOT solve this issue for you. You will need to do it manually (as you mentioned). Or if you want to be more accurate, you can save the nounce in a database (I don't use moralis, but for server side with high throughput I used a redis entry to store the nounce in the past). I think it will be more problematic for client side, as you don't have this level of control.

Comment: yeah i think for the games like p2e and to process many transactions in real-time, having multiple admin wallets to process tx in batch would be the way to go. I just want to know how real world prod level p2e games tackle this problem.